# Using Powershell to open a RDP session with FQDN

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to use Powershell to open an RDP Connection to a server and before it starts the connection I want it to check AD, and confirm the server exist and pull the FQDN and use the FQDN for the connection name.

```
function Connect-RDP
{

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ComputerName,
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential
)

# take each computername and process it individually
$ComputerName | ForEach-Object {


    mstsc.exe /v $_ /f
}
}
```

This is what I use right now but it doesn't check AD and I am not sure how to incorporate that into the script.

any help getting pointed in the right direction is appreciated.

Luke

Comment: Do you have access to the AD cmdlets. `Get-Adcomputer` would work for this. `[adsi]` would work if you don't have those

Comment: @Matt would it be get-ADObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the AD cmdlets this could be done rather easy.

```powershell
$ComputerName | ForEach-Object{Get-ADComputer $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSHostName | ForEach-Object {
    mstsc.exe /v $_ /f
}
```

This will take each name and attempt to get the computer object. If it does not exist then no error will be displayed and the entry will be skipped.

**Update**

`-ErrorAction` was not working the way I wanted it to in my above code. I used a try catch block instead. If nothing else it is another example

```powershell
$ComputerName | ForEach-Object{
    Try{
        $computer = $_
        mstsc.exe /v (Get-ADComputer $computer -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSHostName) /f
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Could not locate computer '$computer' in AD." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

**Note:** I think the name `$ComputerName` is misleading since you are treating it like an array.

Comment: I would change "computername", Actually I am not sure why I even made it a loop since I only connect to one at a time, but this helps, Thanks!

Comment: @Luke If that is the case then just remove the whole loop structure and keep its contents. It will be fine. I was wondering why you would connect to multiple machines at once anyway.

Comment: It is a piece of code that I believe one of my co workers got from a script website and I just kept it that way, but I removed the loop and added the search into the Get-ADComputer so it will search our whole forest not just the one domain that my workstation is in.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it (requires module ActiveDirectory):

```
$ComputerName | % {

    try {
    $fqdn = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $_).DNSHostname
    }catch{//do whatever you want with the error}

    if($fqdn){
    mstsc.exe /v $fqdn /f
    }

 }
```

Comment: Since it is possible to get errors it would be advised to do some handling with `Get-ADComputer`.

Comment: wise words, you know i´m lazy